# Envoyer un e-mail à deux personnes ayant le même prénom

Tags: salutations, correspondance, prénoms

Je dois envoyer un e-mail à deux personnes ayant le même prénom. Comment puis-je commencer l'e-mail?

- *Chers Francks*
- *Chers Franck et Franck*

…?

Comment: Je propose de commencer par : `Bonjour messieurs,`. Cela ne trouve pas une solution pour `Chers [...]` mais est une solution de rechange selon moi.

Comment: @Sifu Oui je préférerais une tournure davantage personnelle et moins formel.

Comment: Personnellement j'utilise messieurs et mesdames, même en parlant à des amis. Dans un cas plus personnel, ça donne une touche d'humour. Dans un cas plus professionnel c'est entièrement applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Comme le fait remarquer Sifu, à moins qu'il ne faille être extrêmement formel (ce qui est rare dans les courriels), je ne vois pas pourquoi on ne débuterait pas un courriel par "Bonjour". On peut très bien s'en tenir à *Bonjour*, mais *Bonjour messieurs* et *Bonjour à tous les deux* me semblent parfaitement raisonnables ici.

Dans l'ensemble je crois que c'est acceptable d'avoir un degré de politesse dans un courriel similaire à celui qu'on laisserait sur le répondeur de la personne en question.

Answer (score 3):

Vous n'adressez le même texte qu'à un lecteur à la fois, le prénom est d'usage invariable,

> *Cher Frank et Frank* est correct,

On peut aussi ne mettre que *Cher Frank* et signaler dans le corps du message que l'autre *Frank* reçoit la même missive.

Si ces personnes sont plus proches, on peut faire aussi un clin d’œil :

> *Cher Frank ... et cher Frank !*
>
> *Cher(s) Frank(s)*

Answer (score 2):

Parmi les formules que nous utilisons dans un groupe de travail entre amis figurent :

- Chers,
- Chers ami(e)s,
- Chers toutes et tous,
- Chers tous les deux, (tous les trois parfois, mais plus de trois on s'arrête à tous)